# Should questions based on single variable integration allowed?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

I am not really a math user here, I'm mostly on chemistry.stackexchange.

What I do know, is that integrals can be easily solved on this wonderful website.

http://www.integral-calculator.com/

Simply plugging the integral you want will give the answer with steps, so asking it here is quite irrelevant I feel.

What are your thoughts?

Comment: Try to input integral from [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2286670/evaluating-the-integral-int-fracx-1x1-sqrtx3x2xdx) question. In general machines are dumber then people, sometimes they take a ridiculously hard route, and sometimes they just don't know how to solve.

Comment: I also feel that we have too many such questions that can be answered by such tools (many would endorse Wolfram Alpha rather than your link). Such questions do offer opportunities to ask/teach about the relevant concepts, which is why we allow them. It is a bit difficult to draw the line exactly somewhere, and most such questions also attract answers void of any pedagogical merit. But, IMHO it is better that we decide/vote on a case-by-case basis rather than try to define a lithmus test.

Comment: @kingW3 I see, this one couldn't solve the integral.

Comment: We do have a requirement (sometimes enforced by the users) that when you ask a question, you show your own efforts with it.  Such efforts might include the results from integral-calculator and from Wolfram Alpha.

Comment: Dilemma: Is upvoting this meta question supposed to mean that one wants to answer "yes" to the question in the title, or that one agrees with the OP's feeling that the answer to the question in their title is "no"? :-)

Comment: @Did, we will never know.

Comment: Sounds like an add/spam for the website you link to.

Comment: @amWhy I cannot control what you think, though I am honest in my attempt to suggest useful things to StackExchange.

Comment: I never said you were otherwise.  I simply offered my initial reaction to your post.  I now understand you aren't looking for honest feedback about the question you posted.  May ye fare well!

Comment: @amWhy "I now understand you..." As I already told you, I can't control what you think. May ye fare well!

Comment: @Did:  and there is the possibility that one wants to protest, via downvote, a post that looks a little spammy, "What I do know, is that integrals can be easily solved on this *wonderful* website: ... [website link then provided]"

Comment: Since one can [google for hits on sites about notation used in mathematics,](https://www.google.com/search?q=notation+used+in+mathematics&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8), such questions here are rather irrelevant, as are any/all questions about [truth-tables](https://web.stanford.edu/class/cs103/tools/truth-table-tool/).  And lets cross off all questions that can be answered through Wikipedia, and let's forbid questions that can be answered by any one of, say 12, texts/ books (we can take a poll on which books, texts)...

Comment: Automated theorem proverbs/ CAS Systems only help to reduce the task at hand, humans are better at explaining and giving insight to a given problem then a machine, it is also to note that some of these integrals as we as a community have seen can be quite a challenge to evaluate.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First of all, thanks to the OP for letting us know about the website.  If nothing else, it offers a very nice interface and is handy for beginning students.

That all said, the question is moot.  In many other topics we answer basic questions to which one may find solutions elsewhere.  For integration, this site, Wolfram Alpha, Mathematica, at the very least, all offer "done out" integrals.  That does not preclude us from answering such questions here.

Three more points: 1) the particular site the OP references seems only to know how to take antiderivatives.  Most of the definite integrals evaluated here require something other than the Fundamental Theorem (e.g., residue theorem, some integral transform).

2) Even if the integral evaluation software has the "intelligence" to use fancy methods, it does not always get it right.  I have had no less than three incidents in which Mathematica got it wrong - I even got Wolfram to admit the software was wrong and they eventually followed through and corrected their software. ([Here's](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1658250/compute-the-series-sum-n-1-infty-frac1n3-sinn-pi-sqrt2/1658310#1658310) an example.)

3) AND even if the answer is correct, some software (Maple is especially guilty of this) puts the result in such a horrible form so as to completely obfuscate much simpler forms.  ([Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/562769/what-would-qualify-as-a-valid-reason-to-believe-there-is-a-closed-form/562810#562810) I describe an example - the horrible answer has since been deleted so you may not see it.)

My point is that humans are still way better than machines at evaluating and explaining.  And even if Math Skynet were to make this not so, so what?  Some of us still like doing integrals by hand.

Comment: I upvoted your answer, due to its helpful arguments, despite my concern about your first two sentences. Introducing a website that may help new learners encountering integration for the first time should happen at the level of the math.se (main) level, in a comment including to the proposed helpful link. What seems to go unnoticed is that praising this "linked website" at first site, (I still don't know that the question wasn't a front for website promotion/spam)...

Comment: ... leaves the door open to any/all eager users who decide to promote on meta websites or apps, personally designed or otherwise, with  links to their favorite site or app for answering questions of the sort x, y, z..

Comment: But, I should emphasize your arguments are helpful, and I agree.

Comment: @amWhy: I am just providing a bit of kindness before getting into a harsh disagreement - I do this here to take the edge off and increase the chances that the OP will read my answer.  That said, you are right and maybe I should have looked harder before providing praise.